# Requests library and validator.w3.org/nu

Tags: python, python-requests, w3c-validation

I would like to use API of validator.w3.org/nu.

Documentation: https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service:-Input:-GET

My code:

```
validaror_url = "https://validator.w3.org/nu/"        
headers = { "Content-type": "text/html, charset=utf-8" }

ip_address = urllib.quote("http://www.artlebedev.ru/")
params = { "doc": ip_address, "out": "json"}

response = requests.get(validaror_url, headers=headers, 
                        params=params)
```

I get:

```
Response: <Response [200]>
content str: {"url":"http%3A//93.185.180.36/","messages":[{"type":"non-document-error","subType":"io","message":"Missing scheme"}]}\n
```

If I take another sample site, non-document-error again.

This error is deciphered here: https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Output:-JSON

But anyway, such error message shouldn't be there.

If I change requests to unirest, everything is fine (there are a lot of messages and they are informative ones). But unirest is not suitable for me because of no Python3 support.

I think, maybe, the problem is that requests can't comply with this "Only "&" is supported as a query parameter separator. ";" is not supported" (this is from validator's documentation).

Well, requests is not a dogma. What I need is just get a meaningful response from the validator, whereas using Python3. If requests is not suitable, maybe I should change it.

Could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do anything bar pass the url and the params

```
import requests
validaror_url = "https://validator.w3.org/nu/"
ip_address = "http://www.artlebedev.ru/"
params = { "doc": ip_address, "out": "json"}

response = requests.get(validaror_url,
                        params=params)

print(response.json())
```

That gives you output like:

```
 {'extract': 'аз... -->\n<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">\n<tr v',
   'firstColumn': 1,
   'hiliteLength': 63,
   'hiliteStart': 10,
   'lastColumn': 63,
   'lastLine': 1369,
   'message': 'The “width” attribute on the “table” element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.',
   'type': 'error'},
  {'extract': 'аз... -->\n<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">\n<tr v',
   'firstColumn': 1,
   'hiliteLength': 63,
   'hiliteStart': 10,
   'lastColumn': 63,
   'lastLine': 1369,
   'message': 'The “border” attribute on the “table” element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.',
   'type': 'error'}
```

There is way too much to post it all.